# Output ACF field choices in custom REST API endpoint

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to create a custom endpoint for the WP REST API that should contain certain ACF fields and their created choices, in case the field is a select field.

This is the code I'm trying in `functions.php`:

```
function test_get_acf() {
    $field = get_field_object('credits');
    $credits = array();
    if( $field['choices'] ) {
        foreach( $field['choices'] as $value => $label ) {
            array_push($credits, $value);
        }
    }
    $items = array(
        'credits' => $credits
    );
    return $items;
  }
```

And this is the function creating the endpoint:

```
  function test_register_api_endpoints() {
    register_rest_route( 'test/v2', '/acf', array(
      'methods' => 'GET',
      'callback' => 'test_get_acf',
    ) );
  }

  add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'test_register_api_endpoints' );
```

However, doing this I get the following JSON output:

```
[
   "credits": [ ]
]
```

So it's obviously not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that ACF cannot find the field you're asking for, According to [get_field_object() documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_object/), it also takes a `post_id` argument which defaults to current post id, in order to only get the field object (outside of a post context), you should either use the field key like this:

```
$field = get_field_object('field_5e380cf7b4bf0');
```

which in this case `field_5e380cf7b4bf0` is the key of your field. If you have to use this method and you also need to retrieve the key dynamically there's an instruction [here](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/get-field-key-by-field-name/) of how to get field key by it's name.

Or pass a sample post id to it :

```
global $wp_query;
$field = get_field_object('credits', $wp_query->posts[0]->ID); // Or just pass a number like 1 if you are sure that a post with that id exists
```

**Note:** If you just created a field an there isn't any post using it yet, it also may result to `false` when you call `get_field_object()`

Comment: thanks that worked for me. getting the field object but passing get_the_ID(). I needed this to create a custom endpoint and serve ACF fields.